# Tweepy blank search

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I've been searching the net for an answer, but I didn't find anything for what I think might be a simple question:

**Is there any way to get 'blank' searches from tweepy?**

For example, get all tweets from location.

I can't send a query with no query field:

```
query=  tweepy.api.search(q="", rpp=1000)
```

It returns:

> tweepy.error.TweepError: You must enter a query.

What I'm looking for is get this query, for example:

http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?geocode=38.376,-0.5,8km

Get all tweets from...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`q` parameter is optional, `geocode` is too (see [docs](http://pythonhosted.org/tweepy/html/api.html#API.search)).

This works for me:

```
import tweepy

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(<consumer_key>, <consumer_secret>)
auth.set_access_token(<key>, <secret>)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

results = tweepy.api.search(geocode="38.376,-0.5,8km", rpp=1000)

for result in results:
    print result.text
    print result.location if hasattr(result, 'location') else "Undefined location"
```

Hope that helps.